# Custom button style shown in GUI preview, but not in actual app

Tags: android, button, styles, drawable

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button_style</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/simple_button</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

And I've verified that simple_button works - if I manually assign it to a button's background, it shows up in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only one styles.xml file? Check this.
Generally has a number of styles.xml files. (ex> values/styles.xml, values-v21/styles.xml, etc...) and Check your device information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/button_style</item>
```

instead of:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button_style</item>
```